# AWS API Gateway: limit requests from a single client

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

AWS API-Gateway allows client to use AWS Signature 4 to sign requests to create the authorization header [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/signing-requests/].

I wanted to know how can apply different throttling limits on my clients as in, how to interpret the auth header in API-Gateway and define throttling limits on it.

I have read that we can set throttling limits for individual API keys. Here, I want to know if different throttling limits can be set based on this **authorization** header.

Thanks.